# How do I export VB form that also has a multi-tab form to PDF

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I have a form "Form1" and a mulitab form "Tabs". There is a next button on Form1, after cliking on that button, multitab form opens. On the last tab of multitab form, I have save button. After clicking on that, PDF is generated. Problem is , 13 pages pdf is generated and it captures the Form1 and last tab of the multitab form. I want to capture the first 11 tabs of the Tabs form too.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging 
Imports System.IO 
Imports System.Threading 
Imports iText.IO.Image 
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf 
Imports iText.Layout

Public Class Form1 Private form1Screenshot As Image
Private Sub createCustomerButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CaptureAndSaveScreenshot()
    Dim tabsForm As New Tabs
    AddHandler tabsForm.SaveButtonClick, AddressOf Tabs_SaveButtonClickHandler
    tabsForm.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub CaptureAndSaveScreenshot()
    ' Capture screenshot of Form1
    form1Screenshot = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(form1Screenshot)
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(Me.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, Me.Size)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function CaptureTabsScreenshots() As List(Of Image)
    Dim screenshots As New List(Of Image)()

    ' Create an instance of the Tabs form
    Using tabsForm As New Tabs
        'tabsForm.AddTabPages() ' Add tab pages to the Tabs form

        tabsForm.Activate()

        ' Iterate over each tab in the Tabs form
        For i As Integer = 0 To tabsForm.TabControl.TabCount - 1
            Dim tabPage As TabPage = tabsForm.TabControl.TabPages(i)

            ' Select the tab and refresh the TabControl
            tabsForm.TabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage
            tabsForm.TabControl.Refresh()

            ' Print the name of the selected tab
            Dim selectedTabName As String = tabPage.Text
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Tab: " & selectedTabName)

            ' Capture the screenshot of the selected tab
            Dim tabScreenshot As Image = New Bitmap(tabsForm.TabControl.Width, tabsForm.TabControl.Height)
            Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tabScreenshot)
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(tabsForm.TabControl.SelectedTab.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, tabsForm.TabControl.SelectedTab.Size)
            End Using
            screenshots.Add(tabScreenshot)
        Next

        ' Print the total tab count
        Dim tabCount As Integer = tabsForm.TabControl.TabCount
        MessageBox.Show("Total Tab Count: " & tabCount.ToString())
    End Using

    Return screenshots
End Function

Private Sub CreatePdfFromScreenshots(screenshots As List(Of Image), outputPath As String)
    Using pdfWriter As PdfWriter = New PdfWriter(outputPath)
        Using pdfDocument As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
            Using document As Document = New Document(pdfDocument)
                For Each screenshot As Image In screenshots
                    Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                        screenshot.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png)
                        Dim imageData As ImageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(memoryStream.ToArray())
                        Dim pdfImage As iText.Layout.Element.Image = New iText.Layout.Element.Image(imageData)
                        document.Add(pdfImage)
                    End Using
                Next
                document.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Tabs_SaveButtonClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim screenshots As List(Of Image) = CaptureTabsScreenshots()
    Dim outputPath As String = "C:\Work\Form\output.pdf" ' Replace with your desired output path

    ' Add the screenshot of Form1 to the list
    screenshots.Insert(0, form1Screenshot)

    CreatePdfFromScreenshots(screenshots, outputPath)
    For i As Integer = 1 To screenshots.Count - 1
        Dim screenshot As Image = screenshots(i)
        Dim fileName As String = "C:\Work\Form\screenshot" & (i + 1).ToString() & ".jpg"
        screenshot.Save(fileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Next

    'MessageBox.Show("Screenshots saved as individual JPG files.")
    MessageBox.Show("Screenshots saved as PDF.")
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Tabs Public TabCtrl As New TabControl
Public Delegate Sub SaveButtonClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Public Event SaveButtonClick As SaveButtonClickHandler

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent SaveButtonClick(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub Tabs_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```